# Upload multiple files and return file info as object

Tags: php

I am trying to create a simple uploader class to use uploading multiple images. I need to return file info from uploadFiles method and use it inside another method (uploadGalleryImages). However if I use return $result then foreach loop stops after first file is uploaded. If I don't return it and just use print_r($result) I can upload all files and see the object in chrome's network tab. Here is my simplified code:

```
public function uploadGalleryImages() {
    $upload_image = $this->uploadFiles($_FILES['image']);
}

private function reArrayFiles($files) {
    $array = array();
    $file_count = count($files['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($files);
    for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $array[$i][$key] = $files[$key][$i];
        }
    }
    return $array;
}


private function uploadFiles($files = array()) {
    $upload_dir = IMAGE_UPLOAD_DIR;
    $thumb_dir  = $upload_dir . 'thumbnails/';

    $file_array = $this->reArrayFiles($files);

    foreach ($file_array as $file) {

       $base_name            = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
       $extension            = strtolower(pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        $counter = 1;
        while(file_exists($upload_dir . $file['name'])) {
            $file['name'] = $base_name . $counter . '.' . $extension;
            $counter++;
        };

       if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $upload_dir . $file['name'])) {
            $result = new \stdClass();
            $result->file_name = $file['name'];
            $result->extension = $extension;
            //print_r($result);
            return $result; // Stops after first file uploaded
        } else {
           return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Save objects to array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store all picture objects in array and return it. Simple example:

```
$pics = [];
foreach ($file_array as $file) {

    if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $upload_dir . $file['name'])) {
        $result = new \stdClass();
        $result->file_name = $file['name'];
        $result->extension = $extension;
        $pics[] = $result;
    } 
}

return $pics;
```